# Maurer-Cartan form defines a connection on a Lie Group considered as a principal $G$ bundle.

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, vector-bundles, principal-bundles

Given a Lie group $G$ we can consider it as a principal $G$ bundle over any element in $G$. 
Consider the Maurer-Cartan form $\omega$ defined by the left translation: for $X\in T_gG$ we have
$\omega(X)=d_g(L_{g^{-1}})(X)$.

To show that $\omega$ defines a connection on the principal bundle we must show the following:

> 1. $R^*_g\omega=Ad_{g^{-1}}(\omega)$, for all $g\in G$.
> 2. $\iota_{\alpha(X)}\omega=X$ for all $X$ in $\mathfrak{g}$.

I have not been able to get very far in my attempt to show 1/
On the left hand side we have $R^*_g\omega=R^*_gd_g(L_{g^{-1}})$. 
On the right hand side we have $Ad_{g^{-1}}(\omega)=d(R_g L_{g^{-1}})(d_gL_{g^{-1}})=d(R_g(d_gL_{g^{-1}}))dL_{g^{-1}}(d_gL_{g^{-1}})$. But I do not see how to reconcile these two sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h$ be any point of $G$ and let $Y_h\in T_hG.$ Then if $g\in G$ we have 
\begin{equation}
R_{g}^{*}(\omega)(Y_h)=\omega((R_{g})_{*}Y_h)=(L_{g^{-1}h^{-1}})_{*}((R_{g})_{*}Y_h)\overset{(*)}{=}(R_{g})_{*}(L_{g^{-1}h^{-1}})_{*}(Y_{h})
\end{equation}
$$=(R_{g})_{*}(L_{g^{-1}})_{*}((L_{h^{-1}})_{*}Y_{h})=(R_{g})_{*}(L_{g^{-1}})_{*}(\omega(Y_h))=Ad(g^{-1})(\omega(Y_{h})).
$$
The equality $(*)$ follows from the commutation of $R_{a}$ and $L_{b}$, for all $a,b\in G.$